# PHP debugging not working in VSCode with Xdebug

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

The following is my launch config :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following image shows that error I got.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you using Apache? have you tried to add x-debug extension to apache settings?

put these lines in your php.ini file:

```
 [xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

and then change your port on config file to  `"port": 9001`

ps: you should download a compatible version of x-debug and put it on ext folder of php.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu system. What is the path zend_extension in ubuntu?

Comment: well zend_extention is for PHP not Ubuntu, I think you can find a good explanation in here: http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/extensions_design/zend_extensions.html